# how to present on the Y axis, format hh: mm: ss Chart.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

how to present on the Y axis, format hh:mm:ss  Chart.js and Angularjs:

```
    $scope.sum = [];
    $scope.valueA = [];

    var tCtrl = this;
    tCtrl.socialChart = {

        options : {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],

                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
            }
        },
        type: 'Bar',
    }

    $scope.labels = $scope.valueA;
    $scope.data = [$scope.sum];

  console.log($scope.sum );
  console.log( $scope.valueA );
```

/////////// result console:

[145,1970,30,60,7661]

['A','B','C','D','E']

script html:

```
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
    </canvas>
```

I would like the Y axis to be hh:mm:ss and the tooltips were displayed in hh:mm:ss.

I do not know how to execute this format from the values in the array $scope.sum

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **$filter** in to the property you want to format. Please make sure you are injected **$filter** in to your controller

```
$filter('date')($scope.yourproperty, "h:mm:ss");
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: when I have such values in the table $scope.sum :`["0:05:45", "0:30:10", "0:00:30", "0:01:00"]` the graph does not display at all

Comment: I would suggest instead of bringing converted value from server , keep it as a normal date and format from chart.js itself using displayFormats https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: did you tried without specify  date format , So I think chart.js will take it as a normal string and display it

Comment: I do not know how to use it: displayFormats chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html . Seconds in number displays, but I want in this format hh:mm:ss  on the Y axis